# Replacing old bathroom exhaust with new

Tags: exhaust-fan

My house was equipped with bathroom exhaust fan.
It's old and I am replacing it with a new updated exhaust fan.
The new fan has Bluetooth music capabilities.
When removing old fan I've noticed my house wires are single wires black,white and green.
However my new fan has two quick connect wires available for black ,white and green.
There is a single switch to turn fan on.
The music part is quick connected after fan installation.
What or how do I connect my single house wires to this double wire fan properly?
The instruction book unfortunately doesn't specify.

Comment: what is the model so we can help looking

Comment: Picture of the fan wires will help also, so we can see the connector.

Comment: It's a Homewerks fan model 7130-33-BT

Comment: Not sure how to insert a picture

Comment: Blindly speaking, one plug is for power in, the other plug is for the BT speaker. Those should be clearly different, the speaker plug only needs 2 wires and should be already coveted to the speaker

Comment: I know I can just slip my existing home wires directly into the quick connect , however unsure which of the two on the new fan to connect too. ‍♀️ there are two optional quick connects for both the black and the white, yet only one existing black and white coming from house . If this makes any sense

Comment: Ok, reading off the new fan wires which are labeled. On both black and white one of the labels reads fan connection , the other label reads light connection as it also has led light as well.  Sorry I missed that.    
But again I only have one existing wire of each color to connect. 

Does this mean I can connect the fan only and not the light?  Or is there some way to get access to both using only the one wire available ?

Comment: Did you see "Wiring for 1 switch operation" on page 5 of the [manual](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:df5902ec-f532-436e-8598-5d8a41e8e7c6) (manufacturer's link, not mine)? Observe the note above the figure.